# Event subscribing pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this class `EventGenerator` that can generate objects of any subclass of an interface `Event`. I would like to allow objects to implement a method that receives a specific subclass `T` of `Event` that will be called when the generator emits a new event of that type.

I would like to follow the Open-Closed principle as much as possible, since subclasses of `Event` may be created in the future.
I was thinking about an interface `EventSubscriber<T extends Event>` with a method `receiveEvent(T)`, but how can I add and store the subscriber in the generator object?

EDIT: Suppose that I don’t have (and will never have) subclasses of classes that implement the `Event` interface

Comment: *"EventGenerator that can generate objects of any subclass of an interface Event"* - looks like `EventGenerator` has a lot of work to do...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko don’t worry about EventGenerator’s cohesion, event publishing is its main role, and it shouldn’t have to know all the subclasses of `Event`

Comment: "how can I add and store the subscriber in the generator object" - do you mean where to store the subscribers or how to store and retrieve them? Would it be possible to have a hierarchy of events, e.g. something like class A extends B extends C extends Event? If so, would a subscriber for type C be interested in events of type A and B as well (I'd guess so)?

Comment: @Thomas forgot to say it, I cannot have subclasses of classes that implement Event, I’m going to edit the question

Comment: Btw, do you have to roll your own solution or would using something like CDI or ActiveMQ be an option as well?

Comment: @Thomas No problem on libraries, but I took a quick look at what you’re referring to, and they seem a big solution related to the problem I’m trying to solve, don’t you think? Maybe I’m wrong

Comment: You could associate every specific event type with the list of subscribers to that event type (by mapping event.getClass() to a list of subscribers); and then cast where needed.

Comment: Well, it depends on the environment you're using. On a JavaEE application server you'd normally have CDI at the ready so defining, firing and listening for events would be quite trivial. Otherwise you'd need to bootstrap CDI or look for another library (e.g. when using Spring I'm sure there's something similar).

Comment: @Daniele that is what I am thinking about right now, do you think it is a good practice to use the `Class` class?

Comment: Well, it is perfectly valid to use the `Class` type as the key type in a map. Though you should be aware of potential issues- in example, do you want the subscriber to be able to subscribe to multiple event types?

Comment: Why can't you use the common listener or observer pattern?

Comment: @BionicCode Because it would mean that the observer/listener has to implement a method for each subclass of Event, when maybe it is not necessary to observe all the events. This also means that a new Event subclass implies a new method that every observer will have to implement.

Comment: But isn't this normal? I mean when I listen to an 'OperationStarted' event than I would write a special handler to do something for this case. Later I decide to listen to 'OperationCompleted'. I would the implement a new handler that e.g. shows a notification to the user. Usually I react to an event and this reaction is event specific. So in the first case I would implement an `IOperationStartedListener`. Later I would have to implement the `IOperationCompletedListener` too. This interfaces define my new handlers. What is wrong with this?

Comment: The only downside I know to this pattern is the tight coupling between the observer and observable. Usually you would use an Event Aggregator to break this dependency.

Comment: "Because it would mean that the observer/listener has to implement a method for each subclass of Event". This is not true. The listener only implements the event handlers for the events he is listening to. In my example only two listeners, although there might be another `OperationCancelled` event.

Comment: I have the feeling you are confused because you are thinking too complicated. Simply define an interface e.g. `IProgressCompletedEvent` that defines a method `receiveEvent(ProgressCompletedEventArgs) : void` where `ProgressCompletedEventArgs` extends `Event`. Then stick with the good old Observer Pattern. You need another event? Simply define another interface e.g. `IProgressCancelledEvent` that defines a method `receiveEvent(ProgressCancelledEventArgs) : void` where `ProgressCancelledEventArgs` extends `Event`.

Comment: When you want to listen to an event, the observer has to implement the corresponding interface(s). That's how it is done. I don't get where your goal is special and requires a different solution. And you don't like or are not able to explain yourself. Such a simple problem turned into something that big...

Comment: You would then store the subscribers either in dedicated collections (in this case you can omit a shared base type for all event listeners) or use a shared collection which requires all listener interfaces to implement e.g. `IEventHandler` as a base type. But then you would also need to use the base type of `Event` as the parameter type. So a dedicated collection for each listener type would be the best. This way no casting is required.

Comment: @BionicCode yes, but that means having a subscriber interface for each event subclass. And as I already said, imagine having 1 million types of events, you would have a class member for each of them which is not good.

Comment: This is not realistic. As I said before: each event needs a handler. This is on the subscriber side. We can say that a subscriber that subscribes to '1 million' events or 20+ events probably has too much responsibility. On the other side is the event source, the observable. An event source with '1 million' or 20+ events probably has too much responsibility.

Comment: But beside this considerations, it is common and logically required that if a subscriber subscribes to N events will most likely have N event handlers. Since each interface defines one specialized event handler you would have to implement N interfaces. All is well. That's the common approach no matter what language you are using. Your thinking is plain wrong, when you expect or plan to have that much events or event handlers on a single type. Events on a class do not have to scale indefinitely. When you listen to 10 different events you need 10 different handlers. Whether you like it or not.

Comment: I really wonder how you are thinking. I never encountered a class with 1 million events nor one with 30. Keep it real. The interface is just the contract so that the event source can know which method to invoke. Java has no delegates like C# has. You are plain wrong. You have to go back to school and read about how event pattern or observer pattern is working and how events are used. How can any sane person imagine 1 million events or event handlers - on a single class...

Comment: Then stick with your crazy Visitor Pattern approach. Reinvent the wheel. Try to shape wheels squared and hope it will roll. Your understanding is wrong for sure. And you are too ignorant to rethink it. Last question: How can a subscriber handle '1 million' different events with a single handler? In a useful way?

Comment: AND if a subscriber could handle '1 million' events with a single handler, wouldn't it be wiser to just use a single event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking about how to store and access the subscribers. Since you don't know the event classes you'd need to cast at some point but that could be handled inside the generator.

A simple storage could be a `Map<Class<? extends Event>, List<EventSubscriber<?>>`.

The subscriber interface could contain a method `Class<T> getEventClass()` which is used as a key into that map when registering the subscriber.

When firing events you'd use the event's class to look up the list of subscribers and get a `List<EventSubscriber<?>>`. Now you loop over those and call `receiveEvent(event)` on them. Because of the wildcard you'll need cast each element to the raw type `EventSubscriber` to make the compiler use the bridge method `receiveEvent(Object)`.

Note that because you're making sure that the same event class is used for registration and lookup of the subscribers and the wildcards are hidden inside the generator it should be safe to do so. We're using things like this all the time :)

**Edit:**

Here's an example of how firing an event might look like:

```
void fireEvent( Event event ) {
  List<EventSubscriber<?>> subscribers = subscriberMap.get( event.getClass() );
  //This cast will cause warnings that you'll want to suppress 
  //via @SuppressWarnings ( { "rawtypes", "unchecked" } ) on the method level
  subscribers.forEach(s -> ((EventSubscriber)s).receiveEvent( event ) );
}
```

Internally the compiler will generate a bridge method `receiveEvent( Object )` which will be called on the raw type you cast the subscriber to. As the comment says this will generate warnings but if you make sure that the lookup will use the same class as the actual parameter type those can safely be ignored.

Comment: Uhm, it is still not very clear where/how to cast eg. Event to EventA? Since the subscriber is supposed to use the specific type (EventSubscriber<T extends Event>) ; then casting should be done by the publisher?

Comment: I didn’t understand your solution that much to be honest... The part of the subscriber storage is perfectly clear, but what are you trying to do with that “bridge method”? I don’t get where the real cast into the subclass happens

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy I added an example, please check if this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Now it’s much clearer. So this receiveEvent(Object) is generated by the compiler? When will the code do the actual dynamic binding on the event?

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy well, if you have a `EventASubscriber implements EventSubscriber<EventA>` that class will get a `receiveEvent(EventA)` method but for compatibility reasons (such as when raw access could happen) that `receiveEvent(Object)` (which will call `receiveEvent(EventA)` by casting the parameter) will be generated as well.

Comment: Now I understand the bridge methods logic much more, and I understand that they slightly simplifies my codebase, thank you.